# Python how to write a set of tuples to csv

Tags: python, csv, syntax

Hi total Newb here and trying to get a mastery of working with lists, sets and tuples. How can I convert the following code into a csv file.

```
print((output2).difference(output1))
```

The full code is found below.

```
import csv

f1 = open ("ted.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
oldList1 = list(oldFile1)

f2 = open ("ted2.csv")
newFile2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
newList2 = list(newFile2)

f1.close()
f2.close()

output1 = set(tuple(row) for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
output2 = set(tuple(row) for row in oldList1 if row not in newList2)


print((output2).difference(output1))
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have an a `csv.Writer` instance, do `writer.writerows(list((output2).difference(output1)))`.

Comment: Your question boils down to "How do I write a set of tuples to csv?".  Pretty much all the code you posted is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  You want the `writerow` or `writerows` method, re.: the `csv` module.  Here it is with `writerow`:

```
import csv

f1 = open ("ted.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
oldList1 = list(oldFile1)

f2 = open ("ted2.csv")
newFile2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
newList2 = list(newFile2)

f1.close()
f2.close()

output1 = set(tuple(row) for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
output2 = set(tuple(row) for row in oldList1 if row not in newList2)

with open('Michal_K.csv','w') as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        for line in (output2).difference(output1):
            wr.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan would want to output all the rows hence would be after writerows. Will give it a go. Cheers

Comment: `[tuple((output2).difference(output1))]` produces a list of tuples of tuples.  Change it to `for line in output2.difference(output1)`.

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  Thanks for the tip @StevenRumbalski

Comment: @MichalK try the code as it's written to solve your issue; edited per Steven's tip.  Feel free to comment if you encounter any roadblocks.

Comment: Works our pretty well . Thanks to both of you.